# Understanding the "subst" keyword and specific line in a makefile

Tags: makefile

I take a course in CPP language and I'm trying to understand the use of "subst" in makefiles (in general) and the specific use in this makefile.

I' have tried to google the use of "subst", but didn't find.

```
CXX=clang++-5.0
RM=rm -f
CPPFLAGS=-std=c++17 

ifndef MAIN
MAIN=./main.cpp
endif

MAINEXECUTABLE=$(subst .cpp,,$(MAIN)).exe

SOURCES=$(MAIN)

all: $(MAINEXECUTABLE)
    $(MAINEXECUTABLE)

$(MAINEXECUTABLE): $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o $(MAINEXECUTABLE)

clean:
    $(RM) *.exe a.out *.class *.ppm
```

This makefile is a generic makefile and can be used to compile any single cpp file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) reference manual:

> ```
> $(subst from,to,text)
> ```
>
> Performs a textual replacement on the text *text*: each occurrence of
>   *from* is replaced by *to*. The result is substituted for the function
>   call. For example,
>
> ```
> $(subst ee,EE,feet on the street)
> ```
>
> substitutes the string ‘fEEt on the strEEt’.

Applying it to your case, the function invocation looks at the main file name and strips the `.cpp` extension (by substituting an empty string for it). It then adds the `.exe` extension to the now extension-less file name.

Comment: Hi thanks. Why $(MAINEXECUTABLE) is both the target and the command?

Comment: @Hodiya2929: Because `$(MAINEXECUTABLE)` is an executable file. One rule *builds* it, and another rule *runs* it.